# How to display a product features dynamically with icons?

Tags: custom-field, themes, page-template

How we can display product features **dynamically**, different for **each product**?

For example, we have a cosmetic product that has **different ingredients**. On the front page, I need to display its ingredients with **icons**. I am not sure that this can be done by **product attributes** like in **WooCommerce**.

See the attached image to understand what I mean. I am also curious how we can add them to products also.

[image: Product page is displaying ingredients with icons]

Comment: Explain your problem more clearly, please. Is product a custom post type? How do you store ingredients right now etc...

Comment: @anton Product is a WooCommerce product. I currently did not store any ingredients. It's a screenshot from a Shopify website [link](https://teoxaneshop.fr/products/rha-micellar-solution). But I want to implement this in WordPress. How I can store this type of data and how to display it? Thank you!

Comment: I think this is not question I can answer just "do this..". It depends on your purposes, your theme etc. For me it's ok to use attributes to store product ingredients. As any other term of taxonomy it has a title and description already. Then, on your shop page you may do different manipulations with this attributes like show them in filter, show products with specific ingredients etc. If you are not a php developer I think it's easier to find a plugin which adds images to product attributes.

Comment: Thank you. It may help me.

Comment: Then you may post another question here, like how to display attributes' images on front end, or maybe you will decide to display them separately (by default they displayed in additional information tab). But on this question will be much easier to give an answer or give a code to achieve this. Good luck)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the popular [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to dynamically add fields and field groups to the product page.

Start with [frequently asked questions](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/frequently-asked-questions/).